# QT getSaveFileUrl method duplicating default file name

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating "Save as..." dialog. I have a problem with **getSaveFileUrl** not setting correct default file name. For example I want default file name to be "Project1", but when I write this:

```
QString pName = "Project1";
QUrl pathToSave = QFileDialog::getSaveFileUrl(this, tr("Select Folder"), pName, "Solution (*.sfp)");
```

It sets default file name to "Project1/Project1.sfp". How this can be fixed?

Comment: You are giving it a directory name of "Project1" in the third parameter.  [It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileUrl).

Comment: @jwdonahue How can I set default file name than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. First: the 3rd parameter of `QFileDialog::getSaveFileUrl()` must be of type `QUrl`, and you are passing a `QString`. The second problem is that, as @jwdonahue said, the 3rd parameter is the initial directory, not a default file name. It can be both, as the [documentation says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName):

> The file dialog's working directory will be set to *dir*. If *dir*
>   includes a file name, the file will be selected.

The quote is from `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()`, but in the documentation about `QFileDialog::getSaveFileUrl()` [says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileUrl):

> The function is used similarly to `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()`. In
>   particular *parent*, *caption*, *dir*, *filter*, *selectedFilter* and *options*
>   are used in the exact same way.

A possible solution, selecting a default directory (in this example the user's "Documents" directory) and a default file name = "Project1.sfp" would be something like this:

```
QDir docsDir(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation));
QUrl pName = QUrl::fromLocalFile(docsDir.filePath("Project1.sfp"));
QUrl pathToSave = QFileDialog::getSaveFileUrl(this, tr("Select Folder"), pName, "Solution (*.sfp)");
```